# Group elements of array by sub string JavaScript

Tags: javascript, grouping, lodash

I have a list of elements like this

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "id_team": "1.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "id_team": "2.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "id_team": "3.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "id_team": "4.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "id_team": "5.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 6,
  "id_team": "2.1.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 7,
  "id_team": "6.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 8,
  "id_team": "1.1.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 9,
  "id_team": "1.2.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 10,
  "id_team": "1.3.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 11,
  "id_team": "1.4.",
  "name": "Name",
}]
```

a shown in the example, i have some string in the column `id_team` that are inside other string in the same column in the array

For example, the main team would be `1.` then `1.1.` and `1.2.` and so on would be part of `1.`

so the result must be like this

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "id_team": "1.",
  "name": "Name",
  "subteams": [{
      "id": 8,
      "id_team": "1.1.",
      "name": "Name",
    }, {
      "id": 9,
      "id_team": "1.2.",
      "name": "Name",
    }, {
      "id": 10,
      "id_team": "1.3.",
      "name": "Name",
    }, {
      "id": 11,
      "id_team": "1.4.",
      "name": "Name",
    },],
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "id_team": "2.",
  "name": "Name",
  "subitems": [{
      "id": 6,
      "id_team": "2.1.",
      "name": "Name",
    },]
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "id_team": "3.",
  "name": "Name",
  "subitems": [],
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "id_team": "4.",
  "name": "Name",
  "subitems": [],
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "id_team": "5.",
  "name": "Name",
  "subitems": [],
}, {
  "id": 7,
  "id_team": "6.",
  "name": "Name",
  "subitems": [],
},]
```

it is doable? i use lodash if it would make it easier.

EDIT

I have something like this

```
    teams.filter(item => item.id_team.length <= size).map((item) => {
        const subteams = teams.filter((team) => 
        team.id_team.indexOf(item.id_team) === 0 && item.id_team !== team.id_team);
        console.log(subteams);
        return {
          ...item,
          subteams,
        };
      }) || [];
```

this kinda work, as it will insert in the sub teams array, but the problem is that this must work for many levels, take this example

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "id_team": "1.",
  "name": "Team Name",
  "subteams": [{
    "id": 8,
    "id_team": "1.1.",
    "name": "Team Name",
  }, {
    "id": 9,
    "id_team": "1.2.",
    "name": "Team Name",
  }, {
    "id": 10,
    "id_team": "1.3.",
    "name": "Team Name",
  }, {
    "id": 11,
    "id_team": "1.4.",
    "name": "Team Name",
  }, {
    "id": 12,
    "id_team": "1.1.1",
    "name": "Team Name",
  }]
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "id_team": "2.",
  "name": "Team Name",
  "subteams": [{
    "id": 6,
    "id_team": "2.1.",
    "name": "Team Name",
  }]
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "id_team": "3.",
  "name": "Team Name",
  "subteams": []
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "id_team": "4.",
  "name": "Team Name",
  "subteams": []
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "id_team": "5.",
  "name": "Team Name",
  "subteams": []
}, {
  "id": 7,
  "id_team": "6.",
  "name": "Team Name",
  "subteams": []
}]
```

in this example there is a team with `id_team = 1.1.1.`, how can i add that team to a sub team of the team with id_team `1.1.` with the same logic, i tried to use the same code recursively but it didnt work.

Comment: There's not a golden function that's going to do it automatically. You'll have to write something.  You could possibly do it with reduce. Have you tried anything yet? Basically map through what you've got and create what you want.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't recommend using map or reduce.  IMO It'll be easier to just iterate over the list and use a recursive tree walker to find the node to insert it at each time.

Comment: None of this comments have been helpfull at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the code of the example, i just checked if the subteams array has data, if it does, i use an auxiliar with the recursive function and assigned it to the subteams.

```
 getSubTeams(teams, size) {
      const filtered = teams.filter(item => item.id_team.length <= size);

      return filtered.map((item) => {
        let subteams = teams.filter((team) => team.id_team.indexOf(item.id_team) === 0 && item.id_team !== team.id_team);
        if (subteams.length > 0) {
          let aux = this.getSubTeams(subteams, size + 2);
          subteams = [
            ...aux,
          ];
        }
        return {
          ...item,
          subteams,
        };
      }) || [];
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const items = data.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
    const id_team = item.id_team.split('.')[0] + '.';
    const current = acc.find(record => record.id_team === id_team);

    if(current) current.subteams.push(item);
    else acc.push({
        id: index + 1,
        id_team,
        subteams: [item]
    });

    return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: i tried this but does not work, return the current length of the array and some dont have an object but an integer

Comment: @CarlosSalazar I fixed the problem, please check it again.

Comment: Now this work equally as the code i put in the edit, but it still does not look for another level in the array, as the element with the `id_team = '1.1.1.'` must be inside the one with `id_team: '1.1.'`  i tried using the code recursive and could't make it work either

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "id_team": "1.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "id_team": "2.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "id_team": "3.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "id_team": "4.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "id_team": "1.2.5.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 6,
  "id_team": "2.1.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 7,
  "id_team": "6.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 8,
  "id_team": "1.1.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 9,
  "id_team": "1.2.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 10,
  "id_team": "1.3.",
  "name": "Name",
}, {
  "id": 11,
  "id_team": "1.4.",
  "name": "Name",
}];

data = data.map(node=>{
  let t = node.id_team.split('.').filter(n=>n);
  let parent = t.splice(0,t.length-1).join('.');
  return {
    ...node,
    parent: !!parent ? parent+'.' : null
  }
});

let tree = (items, id = null) =>
  items
    .filter(item => item.parent === id)
    .map(item => ({ ...item, subTeams: tree(items, item.id_team) }));


console.log(JSON.stringify(tree(data),null,2));
```

Comment: This work equally as the code i put in the edit, but it still does not look for another level in the array, as the element with the `id_team = '1.1.1.'` must be inside the one with `id_team: '1.1.'`  i tried using the code recursive and could't make it work either

Comment: If you need unlimited dept, you can spend time and make a recursive function.